# Is omitting articles in parentheses allowed?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article, parenthesis

My question concerns the omission of articles when a word/phrase is followed by additional facts in parentheses or brackets (the noun phrases in the brackets are related to the noun before the parentheses or the brackets). This is not about general article (*a/an/the*) usage rules.

Here is an example text (Firm-A is a stand-in for a real company's name):

> a) *I am submitting this job prospecting letter in the hope of starting a career with Firm-A (London office, entry level IT specialist position).*
>   
>   b) *I am submitting this job prospecting letter in the hope of starting a career with Firm-A (**a** London office, **an** entry level IT specialist position).*
>   
>   c) *I am submitting this job prospecting letter in the hope of starting a career with Firm-A (**the** London office, **the** entry level IT specialist position).*

Here is another example text:

> d) *I am particularly attracted to working at Firm-A because of the firm’s <1st fact, 2nd fact, ...>, and solid prospects for extensive development (cooperation with Firm-B, alleged acquisition of Firm-B shares)*
>   
>   e) *I am particularly attracted to working at Firm-A because of the firm’s <1st fact, 2nd fact, ...>, and solid prospects for extensive development (**a** cooperation with Firm-B, **an** alleged acquisition of Firm-B shares).*
>   
>   f) *I am particularly attracted to working at Firm-A because of the firm’s <1st fact, 2nd fact, ...>, and solid prospects for extensive development (**the** cooperation with Firm-B, **the** alleged acquisition of Firm-B shares).*

Or should the wordings in the parentheses be paraphrased? (for example, *"by the means of a cooperation with"*, *"due to (an/the) alleged acquisition"*)

Should articles be used or could they be omitted?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Being a user of this site for a while, I can say that it's less than likely that provoking comments will have any positive effect. This site seems to focus on one specific issue in each question. Proofreading and having lots of mini-questions are discouraged. In my opinion, your question is a borderline proofreading request. It also contains many smaller questions inside, which makes it more difficult for answerers to answer all of them. It might be better if you split them into several questions, make the questions clear and focused, and tell more about your opinions on the choices.

Comment: After re-reading your question over and over, I could understand your question a little better. What confused me the most (and it still does) was the word "bracket". I'm not sure which brackets you referred to. It might be better to refer to () as parentheses, [] as brackets, {} as curly braces, and <> as angle brackets. I will try to reformat your question. Please feel free to re-edit my version as you see fit.

Comment: thnx. the question is about grammar rules (so i guess it might be irrelevant whether I got examples from a cover letter or from my head). if you provide me with a guidance - then i would have an opportunity to do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer your question, mostly because the use of parentheses in this sense is strongly discouraged in formal written English.

As a rule of thumb, if you can omit parentheses, omit parentheses. There seems to be no reason to use them here; your sentences make just as much sense without them:

> I am submitting this letter in the hope of starting a career with Firm-A in its London office as an entry level IT specialist.

Likewise:

> I am particularly attracted to working at Firm A because of the firm’s <1st fact, 2nd fact, ...>, and solid prospects for extensive development, such as Firm A's cooperation with Firm B and the alleged acquisition of Firm-B shares.

Over-reliance on parentheses makes your writing sound slapdash and disorganized.

Also: I don't know what you're trying to say in your second example, but I'm pretty sure "alleged" is not the word you want to use; it strongly implies that the person has been accused of a crime or other misconduct.

Comment: thnx. for some reason i thought otherwise about over-reliance on (). that is, i believed that it is better for reader to have an opportunity to ignore additional-info-in-parentheses.